# How to update the changes to this active record into the associated database table Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I need to update data in afterSave() method.

SummaryField is ActiveRecord class

I'm trying to use this code:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    $sumField = new SummaryField();
    if ($insert==true)
    {
        $sumField->field_id = $_POST['Scientist']['field_name'];
        $sumField->scientist_id = $this->scientist_id;
        $sumField->save();
    }
    else
    {
        $sumField = SummaryField::findOne($this->scientist_id);
        $sumField->field_id = $_POST['Scientist']['field_name']; 
        $sumField->scientist_id = $this->scientist_id;
        $sumField->update();
    }
}
```

So, save() method are working, but when we call ELSE statement:

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

on this  `$sumField->field_id = $_POST['Scientist']['field_name'];`

I can't use new stdClass();

Comment: seems findOne don't get the related model .. try var_dump($this->scientist_id) ..

Comment: Are you sure you have a id = 47 in your SummaryField table ?? check it plaese .. otherwise  .. check the content fo $_POST..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you must define the correct query  for find ..

try indicating the column_name  .. this way

```
$sumField = SummaryField::find()->where(['scientist' => $this->scientist_id])->one();
```